# Vue - Disable browser back button from clearing URL query

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

So I got a Vue app. That when a query of certain values enters the URL bar, a component starts and display things, but when the query gets removed, so does the component.

Every time I press the back button it removes the query (expected behavior). So I want to stop the browser from removing the query string (or go back before the query string was applied) by asking the user if they are sure they want to leave, if yes then normal behavior, if no then don't go back and continue with current.

I have tried the following:

```
window.onbeforeunload
window.onpopstate
window.onhashchanged
```

I also tried to add the query back after it removes it, but that refreshes the page.

But all of them doesn't work for this specific problem. Here is how I call the component:

```
<exampleComponent v-if="$route.query.exampleQuery"></exampleComponent>
```

Here is how I add the query parameters to the URL:

```
handle.$router.push('?exampleQuery=' + _id);
```

**Edit**

I have tried navigation guards now as well. But the thing is, it is not a route change when you add query params, so when the browser's back button get pressed, it doesn't fire beforeRouteLeave/beforeRouteUpdate. I have added on the component and on the parent, but just nothing:

```
beforeRouteUpdate (to, from, next) {
    const answer = window.confirm('Do you really want to leave? you have unsaved changes!')
    if (answer) {
      next()
    } else {
      next(false)
    }
},
```

My url:

```
http://www.example.com/library?id=huf2i783fh8
```

Then `<ResourceView v-if="$route.query.res"></ResourceView>` will startup the component. When the user press back on the browser, my url change to:

```
http://www.example.com/library
```

Then it closes/stops the component, but it shouldn't, it needs to ask `are you sure?` then on confirm change, and not on cancel.

Comment: Did you try to store somewhere the current query ? Redux, Cookies ? And look there to know if the query is still there or not ?

Comment: Take a look at [navigation guards](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#in-component-guards)

Comment: @MatJ The thing is the route doesn't change at all, it is only the query params that gets removed. So the guards will never fire?

Comment: `$router.push` changes the route, even if the same route, it will call the concerned beforerouteupdate guard.

Comment: The browser's back button changes the query params

Comment: Navigation guards trigger when browser already has changed the URL. You have 2 options here: either you `preventDefault` in `window.onbeforeunload `, either you use navigation guards and restore the url params again.

Comment: @deathangel908 I have tried the `window.onbeforeunlod`, but it still clears the query params. Ive tried to add them back, but if I add them back the page refreshes and it shouldn't. Also the guards doesn't even trigger.